How do I add delay to the effects of a geometry node?
I am creating a robot with 8 identical arms arranged in a circle (a bit like an octopus). I have modelled and rigged one arm, then I made a simple geo node modifier which rotates the arm separately by 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270 and 315 deg using a 'transform' node, then joining each rotation together using a 'join geometry' node. Since the armature modifier is before the geo node modifier, I can animate the rigged arm and all the other arms copy it's movement. However, I want there to be a delay between the arms' movements (example, first arm starts it's keyframed movement, 10 frames later the arm to it's left starts doing the same movement, 10 frames later the arm to that one's left starts moving, all the way around the circle). Is there a way to do this using geo nodes or am I best to use another method?

Unfortunately, geonodes can't evaluate an armature in a posture of choice. You can animate the posture and geonodes can access the posture of the current frame. You can have multiple duplicates of the armature and so an access to multiple postures at once, or you can have a simulation zone gathering data of all possible postures. Other than that you can try to reproduce the animation within geonodes to be able to calculate any position on demand.
